# Why is my RecyclerView Duplicating Rows in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am retrieving Firebase data shown in the link below. The RecyclerView shows multiple copies of what should be one row and I can not figure out why. The key for each section in the database should be the same as the title for each row in the RecyclerView.

Fibebase Data Link [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BavSY.png)

[The output of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G1Up.jpg)

using this code

```
    var benefitSpinner = benefitListSpinner

    val spinnerSelection = arrayOf("National", "Texas", "Iowa", "Alabama")

    benefitSpinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, spinnerSelection)

    benefitSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            location = "National"
        }

        override fun onItemSelected(
            parent: AdapterView<*>?,
            view: View?,
            position: Int,
            id: Long
        ) {

            location = spinnerSelection.get(position)

            fetchNationalBenefits()

        }

    }

}

val benefitMap = LinkedHashMap<String, Benefit>()

private  fun refreshRecyclerViewMessages(){


    benefitMap.values.forEach{
        adapter.add(BenefitItem(it))


    }
}

private fun fetchNationalBenefits() {

    benefitMap.clear()
    adapter.clear()

    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/$location")
    ref.addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener{

        override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
            p0.children.forEach{
                val benefitItem = p0.getValue(Benefit::class.java) ?: return

                benefitMap[p0.key!!] = benefitItem

            }
            refreshRecyclerViewMessages()
        }

        override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {

        }
        override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {

        }
        override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {

        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`onChildAdded` is called once for every of your "/$location/*" items.

If I understand your intention correct, you want to call `adapter.add(item)` for every such item. But instead you're calling `refreshRecyclerViewMessages` which adds *all* the items from `benefitMap` to `adapter` every time and that creates the duplicates.

To fix the problem you have to get rid of the loop (`forEach` call) in `refreshRecyclerViewMessages`, just add the new item you've got in `onChildAdded` to the adapter.

Comment: thanks you pointed me in the right direction. I forgot to add adapter.clear() in the refreshRecyclerViewMessages